# 'Screenshot' package is not saving the image in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to save a picture of widget which contains a image and a few texts with it.
I tried the screenshot package and it is working perfectly fine with the Text widgets and a few others as well, but when I try to put a image inside it and save the screenshot saves the blank image with no image in it.
Here is the code, and to be clear I'm not trying to save this image only which is already in my assets but with a few other widgets around it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';
import 'package:stationary/utils/app_images.dart';

import 'card_screen/components/save_image.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  Uint8List? _imageFile;
  ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("buildt");
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Screenshot(
        controller: screenshotController,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Header", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3),
            SizedBox(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  screenshotController.capture().then((image) {
                    //Capture Done
                    setState(() {
                      _imageFile = image!;
                      print(_imageFile == null);
                    });
                    saveInBrowser(image!);
                  }).catchError((onError) {
                    print(onError);
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                    width: 300.0,
                    height: 500.0,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/clean-code.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
            ),
            Text("I am subtitle place holder",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Save In Browser function

```
void saveInBrowser(Uint8List bytes) {
  final dataUri = 'data:text/plain;base64,${base64.encode(bytes)}';

  html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
    ..href = dataUri
    ..download = 'image.png'
    ..dispatchEvent(html.Event.eventType('MouseEvent', 'click'));
}
```

I was trying to save the image and texts as the screenshot but got only the widgets and when tried to work with images only got the blank.

Comment: what text? you haven't any text widget!

Comment: Yes, I haven't added it here because that works perfectly fine. I'm just trying to screenshot this image.

Comment: In case you want the exact situation with added texts, I've updated the code.

Comment: could you also include saveInBrowser?

Comment: Yes, I've added it now! Really sorry that I forgot to mention a key function in my problem.

Comment: you want to download the screenshot in flutter web?

Comment: I want it on both mobile app and web. But I was testing it on web and found it doesn't save the picture?

Comment: by save mean download or save in shared pref?

Comment: I want to download it, so the use can view it from gallary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [image_downloader_web](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader_web) package like this:

```
Future<void> saveInBrowser(Uint8List bytes) async{
  final WebImageDownloader _webImageDownloader = WebImageDownloader();

  await _webImageDownloader.downloadImageFromUInt8List(uInt8List: bytes);
}
```

and also you need to run it in release mode according to this open github [issue](https://github.com/SachinGanesh/screenshot/issues/114), run this in terminal:

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 3344 --release --web-renderer canvaskit --dart-define=BROWSER_IMAGE_DECODING_ENABLED=false
```

also remember to build it with this config too.

Comment: I'll check it and let you know

Comment: Actually the problem remains the same. It saves the image, but the image in the widget tree is not added to image. Instread it is blank

Comment: Yes actually. It's working. I'm now able to save the screenshot.  Thank you for the solution. :) However, can we save this screenshot as png? It's jpg currently

Comment: sorry I don't know how to do that, may you need to convert it to png before download it, or may be use different way to download it.

Comment: Okay! I'll look for that. Thank you for your help